# Ajax Cross Domain Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get variables from an external domain using ajax and then create pre-filled form fields with the data, but i cant seem to get it to work.

I am a bit of a noob to JavaScript it might be something stupid but i just can't figure out why it is not working.

```
 <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function xss_ajax(url) {
        var script_id = null;
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        script.setAttribute('src', url);
        script.setAttribute('id', 'script_id');

        script_id = document.getElementById('script_id');
        if(script_id){
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(script_id);
        }

        // Insert <script> into DOM
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    function callback(data) {

    var counter = 1;
    var limit = 3;
    var txt = '';

    for(var key in data) {

          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]' value=" + data[key] +">";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
;
        }
    }

    var url = "http://myserver.com/test.php";

</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="xss_ajax(url);">Get Data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The script on the external domain.

```
callback({"firstname":"John", "lastname":"Smith", "email":"john.smith@johnsmith.com"});
```

Comment: What is not working? Errors, what browsers, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into JSONP. Also using a library to handle the request will help exponentially, checkout jQuery or Extjs. Heres a [blog post](http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/) that should give you a hand.